# If Iterators returned by HashSet, ArrayList are fail-fast, how can we use iterator remove() to remove elements from Collection

Tags: java, collections

As we all know that `Iterator`s returned by `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, `HashSet` etc. are fail-fast, but while using iterator's `remove()` doesn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. How?

fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if a collection is modified while iterating over it. But while removing elements from `ArrayList` or `HashSet` using iterator's `remove()`, doesn't throw any `ConcurrentModificationException`. Please explain elaborately.

Thanks

Comment: Why dn't you look at the source code? It comes with the JDK. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l847: it updates the expectedModCount after calling the list's remove method. As simple as that.

Comment: Are you asking _why_ this behavior exists? Or are you asking _how_ this behavior is implemented?

Answer (score 6):

> but while using iterator's remove() doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException. How?

Because that behaviour is explicitly documented.

For [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

For [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the Iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

If instead you're asking *how that's achieved*, well, the source code (at least for OpenJDK) is freely available (and likely explorable directly from your IDE) :)

Answer (score 0):

It is achieved as follows:

The collection contains a `private int` member called `modificationCount` (or something like that.)  Each time you use one of the methods that modify the collection, this `modificationCount` is incremented.  When you create an iterator on a collection, the iterator takes notice of the current value of `modificationCount` of the collection, and each time you invoke the iterator it makes sure that `modificationCount` has not changed, so as to ensure that the collection has not been modified while iterating.  If the iterator finds that `modificationCount` has changed, it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

When you delete via the `iterator`, the iterator refrains from incrementing the `modificationCount` of the collection.  It is that simple.